# Lifts of relative homotopic paths to the same base point $\Rightarrow$ The lifts homotopic and agree on the end point.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ a covering map, $a,b : I\rightarrow Y$  are relatively homotopic to each other: $a \simeq_{\partial I} b $ (denoting $F:I\times[0,1] \rightarrow Y$ the homotopy between $a$ and $b$). The lifts $\tilde{a} , \tilde{b}$ satisfies $\tilde{a}(0)=\tilde{b}(0)$. I wish to prove that $\tilde{a}(1) = \tilde{b}(1)$ and $\tilde{a} \simeq \tilde{b}$.

For $\tilde{a}(1) = \tilde{b}(1)$ I tried to show by using the homotopy lifting property of $F$, and use the homotopy $G:I\times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ satisfies:  $G_0 = \tilde{a}$ and $p\circ G_t =F_t$. Then I took two approaches:

1. Show the existence of a lift $\gamma$ of $b$ such that $\gamma(0) = \tilde{a}(0)$ and $\gamma(1) = \tilde{a}(1)$ then from path lifting uniqueness $\gamma$ must be equal to $\tilde{b}$.
2. Show that $G_1$ and $\tilde{b}$ agree in one point and then by theorem they agree on all points. Yet this approach (which I didn't succeeded to prove), just satisfies the fact $\tilde{a} \simeq \tilde{b}$ but as fat as I understand doesn't promise $\tilde{a}(1) = \tilde{b}(1)$.

This post is very similar, relating to loops which are lifted to the same base point:
[Are the lifts of homotopic curves necessarily homotopic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360583/are-the-lifts-of-homotopic-curves-necessarily-homotopic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tilde a,\tilde b:I\rightarrow X$ be lifts of $a,b:I\rightarrow Y$ satisfying $p\circ \tilde a=a$, $p\circ \tilde b=b$, and let $F_t:a\simeq_{\partial I}b:I\rightarrow Y$ be a relative homotopy satisfying $F(s,0)=a(s)$, $F(s,1)=b(s)$, $F(0,t)=a(0)=b(0)$ and $F(1,t)=a(1)=b(1)$. Now apply the HELP lemma in the diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    0\times I\cup I\times \partial I@>G'>> X\\
    @Vi  V V @VVpV\\
    I\times I @>F>> Y
\end{CD}$\require{AMScd}$

where $G'(s,0)=\tilde a(s)$, $G'(s,1)=\tilde b(s)$, $G'(0,t)=\tilde a(0)=\tilde b(0)$. Note that $p\circ G'=F\circ i$. From the data the HELP lemma gives a map $G:I\times I\rightarrow X$ satisfying

$$G(s,0)=\tilde a (s),\quad G(s,1)=\tilde b(s),\quad G(0,t)=\tilde a(0)=\tilde b(0),\quad p\circ G(s,t)=F(s,t).$$

In particular $p(G(s,1))=p(\tilde a(1))=p(\tilde b(1))=F(s,1)=a(0)=b(0)$, so the assignment $s\mapsto G(s,1)$ is a path in $X$ contained in the fibre over $a(0)=b(0)$, going from $\tilde a(0)$ and ending at $\tilde b(0)$. Since the covering projection has discrete fibres such a path must be constant.

Hence $\tilde a(1)=\tilde b(1)$, and $G:\tilde a\simeq_{\partial I}\tilde b$ is a relative homotopy.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't understand the next move: defining $G'$ as satisfies the commutative diagram. But why $G(s,1) = \tilde{b}(s)$ ?  (In the answer it appears $G(s,0)=\tilde{b}(0)$ but I assume it is a typo). $G$ derives from the homotopy lifting property, buy how can one  determine $G(s,1)$ ,which is indeed $b$'s lift, equals to $\tilde{b}$ ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo! We have $G(s,t)=G\circ i(s,1)=G'(s,1)=\tilde b(s)$.

Comment: I'm really sorry- all I know is that $G(s,1)$ is a lift of $b (= F(s,1)$. in your comment, $G(s,1) = G \circ i(s,1) =_{***} G'(s,1)$, when $G'(s,1)$ is $\tilde{b}$ but why $G(s,1)$ isn't a different lift of $b$ it doesn't even have to be to the same base point $\tilde{a}(0) = \tilde{b}(0)$. I tried to find a mutual point which $G(s,1)$ and $G'(s,1) = \tilde{b}(s)$ agrees on, then to use the lemma a cited in the question, but couldn't find such a point. Just to make sure, $G$ in your answer is the homotopy derived from the homotopy lifting property, right?

Comment: $G$ is a lift of $F$, but it is also an *extension* of $G'$ along the acyclic cofibration $i$. Since $I\times\partial I\subset 0\times I\cup I\times\partial I$ it holds that $G(s,1)=G\circ i(s,1)=G'(s,1)=\tilde b(s)$, where the last equality follows from the definition of $G'$. I'm not sure exactly sure where the difficulty is, the map $G$ is given by the HELP lemma, not the HL property. The HELP lemma gives a diagonal map $G:I\times I\rightarrow X$ in the diagram I drew making everything commute. A good reference seems to be Spanier's Algebraic Topology, Lemma 7.2.5, pg 375.

Comment: My problem was that I wasn't familiar with the homotopy extension property, I didn't manage yet to search in Spanier's book. But if I understand you correctly, $(I\times\{0,1\} \cup \{0\} \times [0,1],X)$ satisfies the HE property? and that's what gives us the homotopy $G:I\times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ ?

Comment: Secondly, can you please explain what promises that $\tilde{b}(1) = \tilde{a}(1)$?

Comment: We have the map $G:I\times I\rightarrow X$ defined to make both resulting triangles commute in the diagram. Hence $G:\tilde b\simeq \tilde a$ is a homotopy covering $F$ satisfying $G(s,0)=\tilde a(0)=\tilde b(0)$ for all $s$. This all comes from its definition. Now the assignment $t\mapsto G(1,t)$ is therefore a path from $G(1,0)=\tilde a(1)$ to $G(1,1)=\tilde b(1)$. It covers the path $t\mapsto F(1,t)$ in $Y$, which is the constant path at $a(1)=b(1)$, since $F$ is a path homotopy. It follows that the path $G(1,t)$ is contained in the fibre over $a(1)=b(1)$.

Comment: Since $X\rightarrow Y$ is a covering its fibres are discrete. Therefore $G(1,t)$ must be the constant path at its starting point $G(1,0)=\tilde a(1)$. Hence $\tilde a(1)=G(1,0)=G(1,1)=\tilde b(1)$, where the last equality follows from the definition of $G$.

Comment: thanks for your help and patience! I really appreciate it!